# Counting problem in statistical mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

Consider a system of $N$ molecules, and they can each possess either property A or property B. No molecule can have no property, or both properties at the same time. Let $x$ be the fraction of having property A, and $-n\epsilon$ is the penalty the system incurs in energy when $n$ molecules exhibit property A, and the system incurs no penalty if a molecule exhibits property B.

I want to find the density of states $\Omega$ for this system, and the relation between $x$ and the temperature $T$ of the system.

I know energy $E$ of the system is: $E = -Nx\epsilon \implies \frac{dx}{dE} = -\frac{1}{N\epsilon}$

$$\Omega (E=-n\epsilon) = \frac{N!}{(N-n)!n!}$$
Because we are saying that out of the $N$ particles we have, $n$ of them have property A, and $N$ choose $n$ is the way we would pick $n$ particles to have a certain property.

We know $$S=k\log \Omega$$
And using Stirling's approximation and some math,
$$S = -kN\big( (1-x)\log (1-x) + x\log x\big)$$

Then I use Maxwell's relationship to find $x$ as a function of $T$,
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dE} = \frac{1}{T}$$

Doing the inversion, we get $$x(T) = \frac{e^{\epsilon/kT}}{1+e^{\epsilon/kT}}$$

The problem I have is, if I say $\epsilon = \alpha k$ where $\alpha >0$, $x(T)$ cannot be a value less than $0.5$, as at $x=0.5$, $T\rightarrow \infty$. Does this make sense? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You always expect more molecules to be in the lower energy state. This is reflected in the fact that at every temperature $x>.5$

Comment: So there is zero probability of even having $x<0.5$? @JahanClaes

Comment: Actually, you can have $x<.5$, you just have to consider negative temperatures (the latter are possible for systems in which the energy is bounded above). There are several questions related to negative temperatures, if you’re interested.

Comment: In your 2-level system, note that the entropy reaches its maximal value when half of the particles are in the excited state. If you keep increasing the number of particles in the excited state, then the entropy decreases, which corresponds to a negative $dS/dE$ and thus a negative temperature.

Comment: You could have x<.5 at an instant in time, but you are calculating the average population when you use the partition function.  And as you have seen, this will always be >.5 for any positive temperature.